# Query to check if Oracle AQ is started or stopped

Tags: oracle, oracle-aq

I have executed following command to start a user queue.

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_AQADM.START_QUEUE('MY_USER.MY_QUEUE');
END;
```

Is it possible to check and confirm if this Queue is started or stopped using a query in Oracle 11g ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the USER or DBA queues view

```
SELECT name, enqueue_enabled, dequeue_enabled FROM dba_queues;
```

Basically, two YES's = started, two NO's = stopped.